# Set multiple instances of a POJO when there is more than one object (as part of POJO) with the same value in java

Tags: java, apache-poi, instantiation, pojo

I am facing a scenario where I need to have a POJO class get instantiated for multiple rows in an excel sheet that have the same value for one cell in each row.  The current code will only instantiate the POJO for a single row.  When there is > 1 row with the same testCaseValidationID (as seen below in the code), there needs to be an instantiation of the POJO for each row containing the same testCaseValidationID, and the other cell to java object are set with the unique values for the rest of the cells in the row.

Below is the method currently performing the functionality:

```
public static TestCaseValidation getTestCaseValidationDetails(String testCaseExecutionID) {
    Sheet testcaseValidationSheet = allSheetNames.get(TestCaseSheetNames.TEST_CASE_VALIDATIONS.toString());
    TestCaseValidation tcValidation = null;
    int allValidationsCount = testcaseValidationSheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows();
    for (int rowIndex = 1; rowIndex < allValidationsCount; rowIndex++) {
        Row testcaseRow = testcaseValidationSheet.getRow(rowIndex);
        String testCaseValidationID = testcaseRow.getCell(0).getStringCellValue();
        try {
            if (testCaseExecutionID.equalsIgnoreCase(testCaseValidationID)) {
                String testcaseName = testcaseRow.getCell(1).getStringCellValue();
                String elementPage = testcaseRow.getCell(2).getStringCellValue();
                String elementName = testcaseRow.getCell(3).getStringCellValue();
                String validationType = testcaseRow.getCell(4).getStringCellValue();
                String condition = testcaseRow.getCell(5).getStringCellValue();
                String description = testcaseRow.getCell(6).getStringCellValue();

                tcValidation = new TestCaseValidation();
                tcValidation.setTCID(testCaseValidationID);
                tcValidation.setTCName(testcaseName);
                WebORElementsDao element = new WebORElementDaoMapper().getElement(elementPage, elementName);
                tcValidation.setElementToValidate(element);
                tcValidation.setValidationType(validationType);
                tcValidation.setCondition_or_text_value(condition);
                tcValidation.setDescription(description);
                return tcValidation;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return tcValidation;
}
```

As you can see, a new instance of TestCaseValidation is created for each single row.  If I need a new instance of the TestCaseValidation POJO to occur for 3 different rows with the same testCaseValidationID, how can this be done? For example, 3 rows where the testCaseValidationID = TC001.  Please let me know for any suggestions, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: you want to instantiated pojo class  row wise or  testCaseValidationID wise ?

Comment: @solankibhargav it should be instantiated based on testCaseValidationID

Comment: What should the method return when there are multiple matching rows?